# Vala can't find gtk+-3.0 Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, compiler-errors, vala, gtk3

I'm just starting to learn Vala (under Ubuntu 12.04), and I'm attempting to follow [this](https://live.gnome.org/Vala/GTKSample) tutorial; however, at the very first compilation step (`valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 gtktut.vala`), I receive this error:

`error: gtk+-3.0 not found in specified Vala API directories or GObject-Introspection GIR directories`

I can't seem to find any information about this on the Internet except that it may mean I don't have the GTK3 .vapi file (there is none in my `/usr/share/vala/vapi` directory); however, I can't find out where I should even download this mythical file if it even is the cause of my problem. Supposedly it's supposed to be included with my installation of the vala compiler.

Again, I'm a complete novice when it comes to compiled languages and I've tried my best to find the answer.

How can I point valac to the necessary gtk3 packages?

**UPDATE:**

I found the `gtk+-3.0.vapi` does exist in `/usr/share/vala-0.16/vapi`; however, it still isn't being found. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It seems for some reason valac-0.16 isn't capable of using its own GTK+3.0 vapi file or something like that. I updated my sources and installed valac-0.18 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Easy just run :

sudo apt-get install gtk+-3.0-dev